# Is there a way to fix this? I keep getting this error even after dropping and creating this same table severally

Tags: php, laravel, database, installation, phpmyadmin

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'fiat_withdrawals' already exists (SQL: create table `fiat_withdrawals` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `bank_id` bigint unsigned not null, `wallet_id` bigint unsigned not null, `admin_id` bigint null, `currency` varchar(30) not null, `coin_amount` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', `currency_amount` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', `rate` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', `fees` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', `status` tinyint not null default '0', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

That's the error i get.

here's my fix for it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fiat_withdrawals;
CREATE TABLE `fiat_withdrawals` (
  `id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, 
  `bank_id` bigint unsigned not null, 
  `wallet_id` bigint unsigned not null, 
  `admin_id` bigint null, 
  `currency` varchar(30) not null, 
  `coin_amount` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', 
  `currency_amount` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', 
  `rate` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', 
  `fees` decimal(19, 8) not null default '0', 
  `status` tinyint not null default '0', 
  `created_at` timestamp null, 
  `updated_at` timestamp null
) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Yet, i still get the same error
Any help, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
-- First, drop the table if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('your_table_name', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE your_table_name;

-- Now create the table
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
   column1 datatype,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   column4 datatype,
   ....
);
```

Replace `your_table_name` with the actual name of your table and `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, etc. with the actual column names and datatypes you want to use in the table.